# How can I transfer props to components located in stack react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, properties, navigation, transfer

So here I have a stack:

```
const GoBackStack = () => {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator headerMode="none">
            <Stack.Screen name="GoBack" component={GoBack} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}
```

What I need to do is to transfer this GoBack component with props like that: `<GoBack any={any} />`. How can I do so in React Native?

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the desired component with another function?

```
const GoBackStack = () => {

    const GoBackWrapper = (props) => <GoBack { ...props } any={any} />

    return (
        <Stack.Navigator headerMode="none">
            <Stack.Screen name="GoBack" component={GoBackWrapper} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}
```

At least, that's how I do it.
GoBackWrapper needs to be in a closure of GoBackStack if the props that you want to pass depends on GoBackStack's state , otherwise it can be outside of the block.

Comment: The problem now is that navigation.goBack() doesn't work

Comment: Doesn't work means there is a Uncaught TypeError: goBack() is not a function? then please try to breakpoint and see if navigation props has that goBack() function in it. if you mean it does trigger goBack() function in navigation props, but it is not actually navigating , you need to investigate if there's other factors in play here like if there's even the previous screen in the stack.

Comment: You can even destructure in the wrapper to be safe also. 
`const GoBackWrapper = ({navigation,...props) => <GoBack { ...props } navigation={navigation} any={any} />`